# Access SQL Server with Windows Authorization from PHP on Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, ubuntu, windows-authentication

I can read data from the remote SQL Server database when I use `sqlcmd -D -S server -d database` command and when I am logged-in as a certain user (OS is Ubuntu).

At the same time when I am trying the execute PHP/Symfony command which accesses the same database I am getting `SSPI Provider: Server MSSQLSvc/... not found in Kerberos database`.

I have tried both drivers: SQLSRV and PDO_SQLSRV with the same result.

How is that possible? Why windows authorization works for `sqlcmd` and does not work for PHP when they both run under the same account?

Comment: Linux doesn't do Windows Authentication out of the box. Is it possible you have a Kerberos client installed and have run `kinit` inside your own account's profile?